# Solo se muestra el primer registro, usando Auth en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Quiero mostrar solo los datos activos de las citas con status 1 que se le ha asignado a un usuario ya que al iniciar sesión este puede ver la información que se le asignó. La información del usuario está relacionada a otra tabla citas, en el formulario de citas se va a elegir al usuario y se le va a agregar una cita. La información que se le agregue al usuario la va a poder ver cuando inicia sesión; el problema es que cuando elimino el registro de la cita (al eliminarla solo cambia el status a 0) el usuario sigue viendo el primer registro de la cita que se le hizo aunque el registro de la cita tenga valor 0.

Esta vista se llama *agenda*: es donde el usuario cuando inicia sesión puede ver la información de su cita si se le ha asignado una. Intenté añadirle la condición `or auth()->user()-> status=='1'` e incluso lo puse entre paréntesis pero sigue igual.

Vista *agenda*:

```
 @if (auth()->user()-> citas!=null or auth()->user()-> status=='1'   )
        <div class="col-xl-8" >
            <div class="card" >
                <div class="card-body pt-3" >
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-bordered">

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-overview">Detalles de su cita</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content pt-">

                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active profile-overview" id="profile-overview" style="margin-left:4%; margin-right:0%;" >

                            <br>
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-lg-2 label "><h5>Nombre</h5></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 ">{{ auth()->user()->name }} {{ auth()->user()->app }} {{ auth()->user()->apm }}</div>

                                <div class="col-lg-2  label"><h5>Cita</h5></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 ">{{ auth()->user()->citas->cita }}</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-2 label"><h5>Mascota</h5></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">{{ auth()->user()->citas->mascota }}</div>

                                <div class="col-lg-2  label"><h5>Edad</h5></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">{{ auth()->user()->citas->edad }}</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-2 label"><h5>Raza</h5></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">{{ auth()->user()->citas->raza }}</div>

                                <div class="col-lg-2 label"><h5>Vacunas</h5></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">{{ auth()->user()->citas->vacunas }}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 label" style=" margin-right:-7%;"><h5>Tratamiento</h5></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">{{ auth()->user()->citas->tratamiento }}</div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            
        </div>
        @else
```

Modelo *usuario*:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','app','apm', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

//Mandar nombre y apellidos para mostrarlos en el selec
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->name . ' ' . $this->app. ' ' . $this->apm;
    }
    public function getFullEmailAttribute()
    {
        return $this->email ;
    }

    public function citas() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Citas','id_users');
    }
}
```

Modelo Citas

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Citas extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'citas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'tel',
        'mascota',
        'edad',
        'raza',
        'tratamiento',
        'cita',
        'vacunas',
        'id_users',
        'status'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\user');
    }

}
```

Controlador que me retorna la vista de agenda:

```
 public function index()
    {
        return view('citas/agenda');
    }
```

Controlador de citas:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Citas;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;


class CitasController extends Controller
{
    
        public function index()
    {
        $citas = DB::table('citas')
            ->select('citas.id as id','users.name','users.app','users.apm','users.email','citas.tel',                  'citas.mascota','citas.edad','citas.raza','citas.tratamiento','citas.cita','citas.vacunas')
            ->join('users','users.id', 'citas.id_users')
            ->where('citas.status','=','1')
            ->get();
        return view('citas.citas',['citas'=>$citas]);
    }


    public function create()
    {
        $user = User::all();
        $data1=$user->pluck('full_email','id');
        return view('citas.formulario',['users'=>$data1]);

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $input = $request->all();
        $cita = new Citas();
        $cita->tel=$input['tel'];
        $cita->mascota=$input['mascota'];
        $cita->edad=$input['edad'];
        $cita->raza=$input['raza'];
        $cita->tratamiento=$input['tratamiento'];
        $cita->cita=$input['cita'];
        $cita->vacunas=$input['vacunas'];
        $cita->id_users=$input['email'];
        $cita->save();



        return redirect()->route('cita.index')->with('success','Registro exitoso');
        exit;
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {

            $data=Citas::find($id);
            $data->status='0';
            $data->update();
            return redirect()->route('cita.index')
                ->with('success','Registro exitoso');

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás eliminando la cita?

Comment: ¿Realmente se está pasando a status='0' en la base de datos? Revisa como se hace un [update](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#updates) con eloquent

Comment: Si, se esta cambiando el status, de hecho tengo otra vista donde solo estoy llamando los registros que tengan status 0 y si me los muestra, solo que no pude ponerla aqui en la parte del controlador de citas ya que no me los registraba como codigo pero si funciona tiene la misma funcion que el index en el controlador solo que estoy llamando los registros con status 0

Comment: La cita la elimino en el metodo destroy en el controlador pero solo le estoy cambiando el status a 0